# freeradius maximum session time problem

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, accounting, freeradius2

I'm using openvpn and free-radius for control user accounts. for maximum session time for an user, free-radius has sqlcounter.conf that control that, but after a connection has disconnected that is useful and cannot destroy a connection.
for control account time dynamically i need another script that do that. but should anytime that a connection has established a trigger run.
is anyway to fire a custom trigger or script when a connection has established? or any way to control session time dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

after couple of search i cannot find a way to do that, but a way to know when a connection is established is use radius log files and radius database.
mysql have not a notify in change method but for log files can use file system notify patches for example dnotify "in the past" and inotify library.
i start using that and post that result.

Answer (score 0):

i do that, with a c program that look for a program change, you can check a user connection to openvpn.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/inotify.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) )
#define EVENT_BUF_LEN     ( 1024 * ( EVENT_SIZE + 16 ) )
int event_check (int fd)
{
  fd_set rfds;
  FD_ZERO (&rfds);
  FD_SET (fd, &rfds);
  /* Wait until an event happens or we get interrupted 
     by a signal that we catch */
  return select (FD_SETSIZE, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  }

int main( )
{
  int length, i = 0;
  int fd;
  int wd;
while(1){
i=0;
  fd = inotify_init();

  if ( fd < 0 ) {
    perror( "inotify_init" );
  }

  wd = inotify_add_watch( fd, "/tmp/test", IN_CLOSE_WRITE);
    if (event_check (fd) > 0)
    {
        char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];
        int count = 0;
        length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN ); 
        if ( length < 0 ) {
            perror( "read" );
          } 
         while ( i < length ) {     struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ]; 
            printf( "New file %s Editted.\n", event->name );
            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
          }
    }
}
    inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
   close( fd );
}
```

but this is not so good code, but its working, can anybody write this code better?